# How should I show that a set is the union of its parts?

Tags: analysis

I am trying to show that, given $M$ = $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $S$ $\subset$ $M$, prove that $M$ is the disjoint union of the interior of $S$, the interior of $S^c$, and the boundary of $S$.

My attempt at a solution:

I am trying to show that M = $S \cup S^c \cup \partial S$ 
where $\partial S$ denotes the boundary of $S$.  This could be poor notation on my part as I'm not entirely sure that this is how boundary points are usually denoted.  As per usual questions involving set equality usually begin by letting some $x$ be an element of some part of the set and showing that equality follows.  However, in this case, I'm not seeing how that would help.

Any tips on how to begin would be appreciated.

Also, I've been asking a lot of questions regarding analysis on here because I find it confusing and I am just beginning to learn it.  I appreciate all the help math stack has offered.

Comment: Show that every point of M must either be interior S, interior of S comp. Or boundary of both .  Show those are the only 3 options and they are mutually exclusive.  Do this by straight definition.

Comment: Take any point in M.  Either there is a neighborhood entirely in S or there isn't.  If there is x is an interior point of S and can not be interior to S comp or a boundary point. If there isn't a neighbor entirely in S it can not be interior to S.  If furthermore there is a neighborhood entirely in S comp.  It is an interior point of S comp and can't be boundary.  If the is no neighbor entirely in S nor entirely is S comp, every neighbor contains points of both and it' a boundary point.  So those are only three options and they are mutually exclusuve.

Comment: Thank you, this makes good sense.  It's fairly intuitive, too.  I don't know why I have a hard time starting these questions, but when I finally see/come up with the solution it's almost frustratingly simple.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x\in M$ with $x\notin S^\circ\cap (S^c)^\circ$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Then there exists $x'\in S^c\cap U$ (else we would have $x\in S^\circ$), and similarly there exists $x''\in S\cap U$. It follows that $x'\in \overline{ S^c}$ and $x''\in\overline S$, and therefore $x\in\overline S\cap \overline {S^c}=\partial S$.

The other cases are much the same - show that $x\notin S^\circ\cap\partial S $ implies $x\in (S^c)^\circ$ and that $x\notin \partial S\cap (S^c)^\circ$ implies  $x\in S^\circ$.